# Need help with Android Emulator Networking

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, android-networking

Here is cmd line

```
"C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Touch -netspeed full -netdelay none -http-proxy localhost:3128 -debug-proxy
```

here is console out when i try to open google.com from emulator:

```
server name 'localhost' resolved to 127.0.0.1:3128
proxy_http_setup: creating http proxy service connecting to: localhost:3128
server name 'localhost' resolved to 127.0.0.1:3128
proxy_http_setup: creating HTTP Proxy Service Footer is (len=2):
'
'
http_service_connect: trying to connect to (null)
http_service_connect: using HTTP rewriter
tcp:(null)(880): connecting
tcp:(null)(880): connected to http proxy, sending header
tcp:(null)(880): sending 27 bytes:
>> 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 20 28 6e 75 6c 6c 29 20 48    CONNECT (null) H
>> 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 0d 0a                   TTP/1.1....

tcp:(null)(880): header sent, receiving first answer line
tcp:(null)(880): received 'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request'
tcp:(null)(880): connection refused, error=400
http_service_connect: trying to connect to (null)
http_service_connect: using HTTP rewriter
tcp:(null)(888): connecting
```

Here is exception from Wikitionary example debug

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: en.wiktionary.org/91.198.174.232:80 - Connection refused
```

About my proxy: it is squid on my local machine and it is configured to route through parent proxy (with auth). This works fine with browser/Android SDK loader/IntelliJ etc., but emulator networking doesn't function.

The main confuse is

```
tcp:(null)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem.  It appears to have started when we updated to Android SDK 12.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of recorded issues with proxy support in the emulator, especially for recent versions on Windows. See the bug report here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5508&q=emulator%20proxy&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

There are some suggested workarounds in there which might help, like setting the proxy in the network settings instead of for the emulator as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referring to localhost on your system from the Android emulator then you have to use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/`. This is because the android emulator runs inside a virtual machine, and, therefore, here 127.0.0.1 or localhost will be the emulator's own loopback address. Also, you don't need to put `-netspeed full -netdelay none` since the properties are set to those values by default. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) for more information on Emulator Networking.

**EDIT:**

You replace `localhost` with another address depending on your situation. If it is a Router/gateway address, then you replace it with `10.0.2.1`. If it is a Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine), then you replace it with `10.0.2.2`. If it is a First DNS server, then you replace it with `10.0.2.3`. If it is an optional second, third and fourth DNS server, then you replace it with `10.0.2.4` / `10.0.2.5` / `10.0.2.6`. If it is the emulated device's own network/ethernet interface, then you replace it with `10.0.2.15`. If it is the emulated device's own loopback interface, then you replace it with `127.0.0.1`. Also, the address 127.0.0.1 on your development machine corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface so if you want to access services running on your development machine's loopback interface, you should use the special address `10.0.2.2` instead. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) for further information on this.

Comment: That may not be relevant in this case, as it looks like the reference to 'localhost' is in host software such as the emulator, not android software running within the emulated device.

Comment: There other address which you can put in depending on the situation,

Comment: Those special addresses only have meaning within the emulator, but the command line option is for the emulator program itself, which sees the PC's view of the network, not the emulated android device that runs inside the emulator and sees this special simulated network.  Indeed, one option is to let it pick the proxy up from a generic environment variable which has no "knowledge" of android emulator networking internals at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (Mac Os X - Android SDK Tools 12 ).
These are my logs from logcat:

08-04 15:33:41.576: INFO/java.net.Socket(256): www.google.com/209.85.148.104(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/209.85.148.104:80 - Connection refused

I use squid as proxy and the logs are:

1312464815.525      0 172.16.1.1 TCP_DENIED/400 1587 CONNECT :0 - NONE/- text/html

It seems that something goes lost...

I've also noticed the emulator tries to use my dns in a request.